# Imposible to debug one create-react-app, I only see the bundle.js errors

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am launching the create-react-app and if throws me one error, but if I see it on Chrome dev tools it refers to one line in the bundle.js that is generated by webpack by default in create-react-app... So it's not useful for debuging.

Are there any way of that Google Chrome Dev Tools show me the error link line to the original .js file and not to the bundle.js one?

Now I only see this error:

[image]

Comment: The error message is still pretty identifying, even if it doesn't tell you where it is. You're setting a `c` prop somewhere which is somehow ending up on some HTML element. Search your code for something like `\bc\b` (regex) or `c={`. Maybe you accidentally pressed the letter "c" when your cursor was on an element.

Comment: See if you can find out anything from the `bundle.js`, you can expand the minified output by clicking the `{}` button at the bottom left in the Sources panel. Maybe it will be enough to figure out where this happened.

Comment: And is not possible to configure a direct link to the original .J's file?

Comment: silvenon, that worked! I found a lost c using the find regex \bc\b. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great! Regarding the sourcemaps (connecting the error to your source), in my newly created CRA project I see that the error is coming from react-dom.development.js, I'm not sure why you're seeing bundle.js, I would have to see the repro project, but mine is frankly equally useless in this particular case.

Comment: Either way I posted the answer, although I don't think it will be useful for anyone else. I'm not sure how to deal with this in Stack Overflow. ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

This particular warning will lead you only as far as `react-dom.development.js`, which is equally useless in my opinion. But if you really want to know what happened, my guess is that you started the production server instead of development.

Either way, the warning is still very revealing and might help you discover the problem even without knowing the exact file. It's telling you that you set the `c` prop to a boolean on a `<div>` element (you can know this from the "at div" part of your warning), which is unsupported. This is was most likely a typo or hitting the key accidentally without wanting to type anything, so you might have something like `<div c>` somewhere.

You can search for this in your project using a regex like `\bc\b`, or search for a string like `c={` in case your mistake was more deliberate.